# Barrel in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

It's possible to do a barrel in Vuejs?

If yes, please show a example, I search in the web, but i didn't find anything

Like js

```
// app/domain/index.js
export * from './negotiation';
export * from './negotiations';

// app/app.js
import { Negotiation, Negotiations } from './domain';
```

Comment: What you mean as "barrel"?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the term "Barrel", but a bit of searching later it seems to mean: "A barrel's a way to put together all the same type or the same usage files in the same place, and then, use a unique file to import them and then export them at the same time." (I got that definition from [here](https://dev.to/luispa/how-to-create-barrels-in-typescript-or-javascript-59ma))

Comment: It's the same thing, but with .vue files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
export {default as MyModule} from './MyModule.vue';
```

Answer (score 1):

When I barrel .vue files I do it this way:

Creating the barrel

```js
 //index.js
 import File1 from './file1'
 import File1 from './file1'
 
 export {
   File1,
   File2
 }
```

Using the barrel file

```js
 import { File1, File2 } from './path'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this will work:

```js
// app/domain/index.js
import NegotiationModule from './negotiation';
import NegotiationsModule from './negotiations';

export const Negotiation = NegotiationModule;
export const Negotiations = NegotiationsModule;

// app/app.js
import { Negotiation, Negotiations } from './domain';
```

(I haven't tested it, so it could not work)

Comment: i try to do a index.js file, export a vue component, but doesn't work.

Comment: Have you created webpack app?

Comment: Imports are part of Webpack.
You should create a project with it using [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html), then place `/domain` and `app.js` into `src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Create index.js file in the same folder as the components (negotiation, negotiations)

> app/domain/index.js

```
import negotiation from './negotiation.vue'
import negotiations from './negotiations.vue'

export default { negotiation, negotiations };
```

> app/app.js

```
import domains from './domain';

const { negotiation, negotiations } = domains;

export default {
  components: { negotiation, negotiations }
}
```